# How to change mail configuration before sending a mail in the controller using Laravel?

Tags: php, email, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4, I would like to change the mail configuration (like driver/host/port/...) in the controller as I would like to save profiles in databases with different mail configuration. This is the basic send mail using configuration from config/mail.php

```
Mail::send(
    'emails.responsable.password_lost',
    array(),
    function($message) use ($responsable){
        $message->to($responsable->email, $responsable->getName());
        $message->subject(Lang::get('email.password_lost'));
    });
```

I've tried to put something like but it didn't work

```
 $message->port('587');
```

Thanks for your support!

Jean

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can set/change any configuration on the fly using `Config::set`:

```
Config::set('key', 'value');
```

So, to set/change the port in `mail.php` you may try this:

```
Config::set('mail.port', 587); // default
```

> **Note:** Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the
>   current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests. [Read more](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration).

**Update**: [A hack for saving the config at runtime.](http://heera.it/laravel-tips-update-config-runtime-persistently)

Comment: I am facing similar kind of problem. I have created a service provider `MailServiceProvider` and declared `Config::set('mail.port', 587);` `Config::set('mail.driver', smtp)` like this in the `register()` function. But it doesn't seems to work. Help Appreciated :)
Original Question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146260/not-able-to-echo-from-service-provider-to-mail-php-laravel)

Comment: You shouldn't change configuration settings at runtime like that. Use a database instead.

Comment: @Saurabh Config::set() works in boot(), at least for me

Comment: you will need this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;`

Answer (score 10):

I know is kind of late but an approach could be providing a swift mailer to the laravel mailer.

```
<?php

$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('host', 'port'))
    ->setEncryption(null)
    ->setUsername('username')
    ->setPassword('secret');

$mailer = app(\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
$mailer->setSwiftMailer(new \Swift_Mailer($transport));

$mail = $mailer
    ->to('user@laravel.com')
    ->send(new OrderShipped);
```

Comment: Thanks, helped alot!

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me on L5.1. Using the Mail facade reverted erratically to the default mail provider

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer didn't work for me, I needed to add the following for the changes to be registered.

```
Config::set('key', 'value');
(new \Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider(app()))->register();
```

Comment: This solution was helpfull when I was working on Laravel 4.2. I'm not using Laravel anymore, you may want to open another thread to have an answer on Laravel 5+. good luck!

Comment: This seems not to work if you are using a queue worker.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a `Laravel 7` application where users are allowed to register and sign in on your application and you intend to enable each user with the ability to send emails through your platform, using their own unique email address and password.

**THE SOLUTION:**

1. Laravel **Model**: first you’ll need to create a database table to store the user’s email configuration data. Next, you’ll need an **Eloquent Model** to retrieve an authenticated user’s id to fetch their email configuration data dynamically.
2. Laravel **ServiceProvider**: next, create a service provider that would query the database for the user’s email configurations using a scope method within your **Model** class and would set it as their default mail configuration. Do not register this service provider within your `config/app.php`
3. Laravel **MiddleWare**: also create a middleware that would run when a user has been authenticated and register the **ServiceProvider**.

***IMPLEMENTING THE MODEL***:

Make a migration. Run these from the command line `php artisan make:migration create_user_email_configurations_table`. Then:

```
Schema::create('user_email_configurations', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('user_id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('address');
  $table->string('driver');
  $table->string('host');
  $table->string('port');
  $table->string('encryption');
  $table->string('username');
  $table->string('password');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Finalize and create your model. Run`php artisan migrate` and
`php artisan make:model userEmailConfiguration`. Now add a scope method into your model.

```
<?php
  namespace App;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class userEmailConfiguration extends Model
{
  protected $hidden = [
    'driver',
    'host',
    'port',
    'encryption',
    'username',
    'password'
  ];
  public function scopeConfiguredEmail($query) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
  }
}
```

***IMPLEMENTING THE SERVICEPROVIDER***

Run this from the command line - `php artisan make:provider MailServiceProvider`

```
<?php
  namespace App\Providers;
  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
  use App\userEmailConfiguration;
  use Config;
class MailServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function register()
  {
    $mail = userEmailConfiguration::configuredEmail()->first();
    if (isset($mail->id))
    {
      $config = array(
        'driver'     => $mail->driver,
        'host'       => $mail->host,
        'port'       => $mail->port,
        'from'       => array('address' => $mail->address, 'name' => $mail->name),
        'encryption' => $mail->encryption,
        'username'   => $mail->username,
        'password'   => $mail->password
      );
      Config::set('mail', $config);
    }
  }
  public function boot()
  {
  }
}
```

***IMPLEMENTING THE MIDDLEWARE***

Run the following command - `php artisan make:middleware MailService`

```
<?php
  namespace App\Http\Middleware;
  use Closure;
  use App;
class MailService
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $app = App::getInstance();
    $app->register('App\Providers\MailServiceProvider');
    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Now that we’ve implemented all that, register your middleware within your `$routedMiddleware` array in your `kennel.php` as `mail`. Then call it up within your authenticated routes middleware:

**Sample:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => [ 'auth:api' ]], function () {
  Route::post('send/email', 'Controller@test_mail')->middleware('mail');
});
```

Here's my original post over medium -
[Enable Unique And Dynamic SMTP Mail Settings For Each User — Laravel 7](https://kayike.medium.com/enable-unique-and-dynamic-smtp-mail-settings-for-each-user-laravel-48e320d381ec)