# How to use and switch at runtime multiple mail drivers in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

Sometime we need to use more than one mail drivers to cover different areas, but now `Laravel 5.3` only supports one, how can we extend it to support more mail drivers and be able to switch the drivers at runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple mail configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546824/multiple-mail-configurations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all Laravel classes, the mailer implements standard laravel interfaces:

```
class Mailer implements MailerContract, MailQueueContract
{
  ...
}
```

If you want to create your own mailers, then all you need to do is implement the contracts in your own class:

```
class MyMailer implements MailerContract, MailQueueContract
{

}
```

To use these different mailers, you will need to overide the `register()` function in the `MailServiceProvider` class to return the mailer instance you require.