# How to conditionally change mail transporter in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

I use laravel 5.3. 
I need to send mail with different credentials (host,port,username, password).

I can send with default laravel config(.env).

But i need dynamic level implementation.

I make array of config,

```
   // Pre-Mail Setup Config.
            $store_config = [
              'list' =>  
                  //SET 1
                 ['from_name' => 'sender1',
                'from_address' => 'from_adderss1',
                'return_address' => 'reply1',
                'subject' => 'subject1',
                'host' => 'host1',
                'port' => 'post1',
                'authentication' => 'auth1',
                'username' => 'uname1',
                'password' => 'pass1'],
                 //SET 2
                [.........],
                 //SET 3
                [.........]
            ];
```

I try the following to send mail, but it won't work.

```
 // Inside Foreach.
$transporter = \Swift_MailTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
                ->setUsername($config['username'])
                ->setPassword($config['password']);

$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);


$message->from($config['from_address'], $config['from_name']);


$message->to('To_Email, 'Name')
        ->subject('My Subject')
        ->setBody('My Content', 'text/html');
$mailer->send($message);
```

What's wrong with my code?

Is it possible?

Or any other solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546824/multiple-mail-configurations

Comment: Actually, that type of implementation is deprecated in laravel 5.
So only i create and specify the version level solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the way to solve this.

Actually Laravel 5 is not fully support this multi transporter config.

so i use alternative package to achieve it.

My Code is ,

```
    foreach ($store_configs['list'] as $store_config) {

        // Create Custom Mailer Instances.
        $mailer = new \YOzaz\LaravelSwiftmailer\Mailer();
        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(
                                           $store_config['host'], 
                                           $store_config['port'], 
                                           $store_config['authentication']);

        // Assign Dynamic Username.
        $transport->setUsername($store_config['username']);

        // Assign Dynamic Password.
        $transport->setPassword($store_config['password']);
        $smtp = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
        $mailer->setSwiftMailer($smtp);



            $mailer->send('template', ['data'], function ($message) use ($queue) {
                // Default Response goes here
                $message->from('From Address', 'From Name');

                $message->to($email, 'Name')->subject('My Subject')
                    ->setBody('My HTML', 'text/html');
                $message->getSwiftMessage();
                //
            });
   }
```

Its works fine with multiple and dynamic transporter.

Thanks to All !