# Laravel: Sending mail from multiple addresses

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

I need to send email from different email accounts, each has its own use, but apparently Laravel only accepts one email address in their email settings to send emails. Is there any way to change these settings so that i can put multiple email accounts?

PD: I'm working with Laravel 5.2

.env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=box668.bluehost.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@domain.com //array of emails?
MAIL_PASSWORD=somepassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: Duplicate the config to for example MAIL_DRIVER2 and use Swift_Mailer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546824/multiple-mail-configurations