# Laravel Mailer with new Swift_Mailer appears as wrong sender domain in Gmail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gmail, swiftmailer

I want to send mails from different accounts in my Laravel application.

Therefore I created a new [swiftmailer transport](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html)

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.org', 25))
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$swift_mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
```

When I send the message directly from the `Swift_Mailer` object

```
// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
  ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
  ->setTo(['receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'])
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $swift_mailer->send($message);
```

I get a mail that is actually send from my mail server:

[image]

However, when I send a mail from a Laravel [Mailer](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html) (as explained [here](https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel)) using the same `Swift_Mailer` object from above:

```
$view = app()->get('view');
$events = app()->get('events');
$mailer = new \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer($view, $swift_mailer, $events);
$mailer->alwaysFrom('john@doe.com', 'John Doe');
$mailer->alwaysReplyTo'john@doe.com', 'John Doe');

$mailer->to('my_email@test.com')->send(new \App\Mail\Test);
```

then it appears in Gmail, that the mail wasn't really send from my mail server:

[image]

When I click on details it tells me that

> The sender domain is different from the domain in the "From:" address.

I actually own both domains. In my `.env` file the FROM address is `****.com` and I wanted to create a new mail from a `****.net` address.

Why does Gmail think I have send a mail via my `****.com` address if use the Laravel `Mailer` class?

Note: This is not a duplicate of [multiple mail configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546824/multiple-mail-configurations/56965347) - this is in fact where I started looking, but the 5 year old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26547428/2311074) was not quite working and I gave this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56965347/2311074), but I am stuck with the above described problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

I compared first the header of both mails, I realized that in the mail using the `Mailer` object I had a respond address with the `***.com` domain.

```
spf=pass (google.com: domain of respond@****.com designates **** as
permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=respond@****.com Return-Path: <respond@***.com>
```

Then I checked the Mailer class (with hindsight, I wonder why I didn't look here first..) and I found the following snippet that I added some month ago:

```
 $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
          $message->getHeaders()
                  ->addTextHeader('Return-Path', 'respond@****.net');
 });
```

So I just had to remove it, now everything works.

In summary, I was convinded the problem was in the `Mailer` class, but it was simply inside the build method of the `Mailable` that I was using.