# How to add multiple email providers in Laraval and switch between them while sending emails? eg:- 2 MAIL_DRIVER, 2 MAIL_HOST etc

Tags: laravel-5

I need to send emails from multiple email providers, one is Amazone SES and another is sendGrid. How can I set the configurations in `.env` file and switch between them when it's needed. Thanks in advance.

Laravel 5.7

Comment: You can have idea from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546824/multiple-mail-configurations

Comment: Thanks, @Rakesh for the link.