# How to send multiple domain email in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I using laravel 7 and tried to send email using Mailtrap
and it's successfully
but actually i want to send `gmail`, `yahoo` and any other mail and multiuser
i using this setting in .env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com //or any other emails not exactly gmail
MAIL_PASSWORD=somepassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=email@yahoo.com //or any other emails not exactly yahoo
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: You want to send emails from different accounts is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting article that describrs the solution to this problem
https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel

Also here is a similar article from an older laravel version

[multiple mail configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546824/multiple-mail-configurations)