# How to send notification based on logged in user mail credential

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 for an HRMS application. It has multiple companies, and each user belongs to a company. Initially, I was using it for a single company. But now, it's for multiple companies with a singular database. The user table has company_id.

**Models**

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'organization_code',
        'organization_name'
    ];
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'company_id',
        'email',
    ];
}
```

**config/mail.php**

```
 return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.office365.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'admin@company1.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'COMPANY1'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','mailer@company1.com'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','company1'),    
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
];
```

The above mail credential is for the company1, but now I have company1, comany2, company3, ... and so on. Each company will have its mail credential.

```php
$details = [
    'subject' => '',
    'greeting' => '',
    'body' => ' ',
    'line1' => '',
    'thanks' => 'Thank you!',
    'user_email' => $userEmail,
    'actionText' => '',
];

Notification::route('mail', $details['user_email'])
    ->notify(new \App\Notifications\UserApprove($details))
```

How do I send the notification based on the mail credential of the company of the logged-in user?

Comment: Laravel unfortunately does not support multiple mail drivers by default (like it does with database connections). You will have to manually create new Swiftmail instance and use it.

Comment: @Autista_z - How do I manually create new Swiftmail instance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546824/multiple-mail-configurations