# Update STMP config on the fly in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My mailing functionality works by adding the configs on `.env` file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=passwordd
MAIL_FROM=info@text.com
MAIL_NAME=Info
```

But my problem is I don't know how to update this configs dynamically. I've try using the helper `config()` but I can't see the SMTP values in `config('app')`.

In case you're wondering why I want to do this is because the SMTP configs will come from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the `Config::set` method, as answered here:

```
Config::set('key', 'value');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438548/385402

but I think it would be better to use DB values directly before sending the email, I don't know if it makes sense that you store them into a config file at all if you already have them in the database.

Comment: That's the thing I don't know the exact key of Mail config that's why I can't use that method. Also, I don't intend to use the values from the config it's just how I do it now since I can't update them yet.

Comment: After checking your link, I think I tried that already but I'll give a go right now.

Comment: Wow, it works! I'm not sure what I did wrong yesterday. :(. Thank you!