# How to change the email credentials

Tags: laravel-5

I have read the basic documentation in Laravel 5.0 for sending email using my gmail account, this is fine for testing but, how do I setup the credentials

`username` and `password` according to each user, I mean this cannot be static on `config/email.php`:

```
'username' => 'useremail@gmail.com',
'password' => 'password',
```

or I'm mistaken?
or what is the correct  way to deal with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation. it might help https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#configuration

Answer (score 0):

The answer was [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438342/how-to-change-mail-configuration-before-sending-a-mail-in-the-controller-using-l), this worked for me.