# Dynamic mail configuration with values from database [Laravel]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a service provider in my Laravel Application `SettingsServiceProvider`. This caches the settings table from the database.

```
$settings = $cache->remember('settings', 60, function() use ($settings)
    {
        return $settings->pluck('value', 'name')->all();
    });

config()->set('settings', $settings);
```

`settings` table:

[image]

I am able to echo the value from the table like this:

```
{{ config('settings.sitename') }}  //returns Awesome Images
```

This works fine on any blade files or controllers in `App\Http\Controllers`

**Problem:**

I am trying to echo the value to `App\config\mail.php` like this:

```
'driver' => config('settings.maildriver'),
'host' => config('settings.mailhost'),
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver()
```

**Update:**

I have created a new service provider `MailServiceProvider` to override the settings in Mail.php like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Config;

class MailServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Config::set('mail.driver', config('settings.maildriver'));
        Config::set('mail.host', config('settings.mailhost'));
        Config::set('mail.port', config('settings.mailport'));
        Config::set('mail.encryption', config('settings.mailencryption'));
        Config::set('mail.username', config('settings.mailusername'));
        Config::set('mail.password', config('settings.mailpassword'));

    }
}
```

But still I am getting the same error!!

Is there any way to override default mail configuration (in `app/config/mail.php`) on-the-fly (e.g. configuration is stored in database) before swiftmailer transport is created?

Comment: How and where are you `echo`ing these values?

Comment: When i echo in my blade files (something.blade.php) using `{{ config('settings.sitename') }}` it works fine. But I am trying to echo it in `Mail.php` file present in `App\config\Mail.php'

Comment: Maybe just stick to the `.env` way of doing it? Ex: `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp')`.

Comment: In my Webapp, I want to give the ability to admin to change the Mail Service Provider details from the Admin Dashboard. So, there is a from in the dashboard to get maildriver, mailport, mailusername etc, and are stored in the database. I don't want the admin to change the code manually.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Struggled for 3 days with this issue finally I figured out a way to solve it.

First I created a table `mails` and populated it with my values.
Then I created a provider `MailConfigServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MailConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if (\Schema::hasTable('mails')) {
            $mail = DB::table('mails')->first();
            if ($mail) //checking if table is not empty
            {
                $config = array(
                    'driver'     => $mail->driver,
                    'host'       => $mail->host,
                    'port'       => $mail->port,
                    'from'       => array('address' => $mail->from_address, 'name' => $mail->from_name),
                    'encryption' => $mail->encryption,
                    'username'   => $mail->username,
                    'password'   => $mail->password,
                    'sendmail'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
                    'pretend'    => false,
                );
                Config::set('mail', $config);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then registered it in the `config\app.php`

```
App\Providers\MailConfigServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: Excellent solution! Works like a charm to me. Thanks!

Comment: Simple, clean, efficient, and Laravel 5.4 compatible. +1

Comment: perfect working in 5.7 also. Also, you can remove the last two configuration parameters. thumbs up for this.

Comment: Does this ServiceProvider always do 1 query (2?) to the database? Even if Mail is not used?

Comment: Wow! That great I loved it

Comment: Every page load you query your settings table. You should cache those results and refresh the cache whenever your setting values changes. See my answer. Also, you can use array_merge, so you only overwrite the settings you want to set.

Comment: AWESOME! PERFECT...WORK LIKE CHARM

Comment: This is a horrible solution. Every request is hitting the database twice just for configuration.  Nobody should be using this ham-fisted hack.

Comment: Obviously this needs to be perfected. This was just a sample code that I used back the. But you could save the config either in default Laravel cache config or a new cache variable key, and then before the hasTable, check it the cache config exists.

Comment: You should move this definition in the boot method as it will throw an error while it is defined in the register method.

Comment: is it possible to filter out data from mails table according to logged in user?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe its usefull to somebody, but I solved it as following;

In a `ServiceProvider` under the `boot`-method;

```
$settings = Cache::remember('settings', 60, function () {
    return Setting::pluck('value', 'name')->all();
});

config()->set('settings', $settings); // optional

config()->set('mail', array_merge(config('mail'), [
    'driver' => 'mailgun',
    'from' => [
        'address' => $settings['mail_from_address'],
        'name' => $settings['mail_from_name']
    ]
]));

config()->set('services', array_merge(config('services'), [
    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => $settings['mailgun_domain'],
        'secret' => $settings['mailgun_secret']
    ]
]));
```

I used `array_merge` with the original config, so we only override the values we need to. Also we can use the `Cache`-facade in the `boot`-method.

Answer (score 2):

After research a lot, finally I found the best possible way to dynamic mail configuration.

I am saving my mail configuration data in the `settings` table, please have a look at the table structure.

[image]

`Helpers/AaapHelper.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Setting;

class AppHelper
{

    public static function setMailConfig(){

        //Get the data from settings table
        $settings = Setting::pluck('description', 'label'); 

        //Set the data in an array variable from settings table
        $mailConfig = [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => $settings['smtp_host'],
            'port' => $settings['smtp_port'],
            'encryption' => $settings['smtp_security'],
            'username' => $settings['smtp_username'],
            'password' => $settings['smtp_password'],
            'timeout' => null
        ];

        //To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config helper
        config(['mail.mailers.smtp' => $mailConfig]);
    }
}
```

`app\Http\Controllers\SettingController.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\AppHelper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SettingController extends Controller
{

    public function sendMail()
    {
        try
        {
            //Set mail configuration
            AppHelper::setMailConfig();

            $data = ['name' => "Virat Gandhi"];

            Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'], $data, function ($message)
            {
                $message->to('abc@gmail.com', 'Lorem Ipsum')
                    ->subject('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
                $message->from('xyz@gmail.com', $data['name']);
            });
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Test email sent successfully');
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

While sending a mail through the `sendMail` function it will first configure mail through helper.

Comment: this works fine when the emails are not queueable but when it comes to queueable mails after setting up everything when i try to get credentials they are empty in my listener any idea why is this so?

Comment: Try to create a job file and put your mail function (Mail::send) inside that. get the credentials in the controller and pass them to the job.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions [here](https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel) is the proper solution to the problem, in case if you're sending multiple emails per request over different SMTP configurations, `Config::set()` won't work right, the first email will use the correct settings, while all upcoming emails within the same request will use the same configuration of the first one, because the `Mail` service is provided as a singleton thus only the initial configurations will be used.

This also might affect emails sent over Laravel queue workers due to the same reason.

Comment: The link you shared isn't elaborate enough. I'm having difficulties implementing it. Any help? I need exactly what you suggested here