# Change Laravel mail configuration during runtime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail, laravel-config

I need to change Laravel Mail Configuration during the runtime. This is because the configuration needs to be changed several times during runtime, not just once on app initialization.

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', $email->email);
    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', $email->password);
    Config::set('mail.from.address', $email->email);

    Mail::to('someone@example.com')->send(new DemoMail('title', 'body'));
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to set new configurations on each iteration, but the configuration is only set once (on the first iteration); all other emails are sent using the design from the first iteration.

I have found solutions using Service Providers. Similar to this one [Dynamic mail configuration with values from database [Laravel]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146260/dynamic-mail-configuration-with-values-from-database-laravel)
The problem is that the provider sets mail configuration when the app is initialized and can't be changed during runtime. So this doesn't solve my problem.

The second idea I came up with is to define multiple mail drivers (configurations), one for each email, and then use the mailer() function to specify which one I want to use on each iteration. The problem with this solution is that I need to create those drivers dynamically; I can't hardcode them.

I searched the internet for the right solution, but couldn't find one.

Comment: Laravel documentation points that you can set configuration in runtime using config helper if you pass an array key value: `config(['your.config' => 'value'])`

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146260/dynamic-mail-configuration-with-values-from-database-laravel

Comment: @MahdiRashidi Unfortunately, it doesn't. I just tried setting it like this config([
       'mail.mailers.smtp.username' => $email->email,
       'mail.mailers.smtp.password' => $email->password,
       'mail.from.address' => $email->email
      ]);  But it only sets it once

Comment: @SHEN I tried something simillar to this, but wouldn't this approach just set configuration when app is initialized. I need to reset configuration each time loop runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution by using Symfony Mailer in Laravel.

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $transport = new EsmtpTransport('mail.host', 465);
            $transport->setUsername($email->email);
            $transport->setPassword($email->password);

            $mailer = new Mailer($transport);

            $mailable = (new SymfonyEmail())->from($email->email)->bcc('test@test.com')->subject($request->subject)->html('email body');

            $mailer->send($mailable);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@itstare maybe this [Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel) can help you to find the way to work with.

the reference discussion is from this [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamic-configuration-for-mail-setup-from-database)

Comment: Option with swift mailer seems interesting, but swift mailer is not supported in Laravel 9 :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).